# file.remove gives "cannot remove file ... reason 'No such file or directory'" although I use "showWarnings = FALSE"

Tags: r, file, cmd

In a (non interactive) R script, running from cmd.exe (on Windows), I have the following line

```
file.remove('text.xls', showWarnings = FALSE)
```

When the interpreter reaches this line and the file does not exist, it writes

```
cannot remove file 'text.xls', reason 'No such file or directory'
```

although I specifically have set the parameter `showWarnings` to `FALSE`. Is there a way to suppress this message?

Comment: Would it make a difference if it was an interactive script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `if` statement:

```
if(file.exists("text.xls"))
    file.remove('text.xls', showWarnings = FALSE)
```

So `file.remove` function will only be evaluated if indicated file exists

Comment: `file.remove()` description should make this condition clear instead throwing 'No such file or directory'.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the function `unlink`:

```
unlink("text.xls")
```

The documentation for `unlink` (`?unlink`) says this about the return value:

> 0 for success, 1 for failure, invisibly. Not deleting a non-existent file is not a failure, nor is being unable to delete a directory if `recursive = FALSE`. However, missing values in `x` are regarded as failures.

This sounds like the behavior you want.